# How to download more than 25 JSON files with AFNetworking 3.0 and also show overall progress?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, afnetworking-3

I want to download more than 25 JSON files and save them to document directory. I need to know its progress. I want to fire all request at the same time.

Comment: Why not zip them all into one file and download?

Comment: No.I cant do that.I just want piece of code , How should I fire all these requests at once?? Queue / GCD ?? How?

Comment: "I just want piece of code". And I want a pony.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified version of AFNetworking 3.0 in which you can show a progress while loading image from server using UIImageView+AFNetworking category.

[https://github.com/rushisangani/AFNetworking](http://Here%20is%20the%20modified%20version%20of%20AFNetworking%203.0%20in%20which%20you%20can%20show%20a%20progress%20while%20loading%20image%20from%20server%20using%20UIImageView+AFNetworking%20category.%20%20https://github.com/rushisangani/AFNetworking%20%20Please%20replace%20following%20files%20with%20original%20AFNetworking%20files.%20%20UIImageView+AFNetworking.h,%20UIImageView+AFNetworking.m,%20%20UIImage+ImageDownloader.h,%20UIImage+ImageDownloader.m%20NOTE:%20If%20you%20update%20your%20pod%20then%20this%20will%20be%20removed.)

Please replace following files with original AFNetworking files.

```
UIImageView+AFNetworking.h,
UIImageView+AFNetworking.m,

UIImage+ImageDownloader.h,
UIImage+ImageDownloader.m
```

NOTE: If you update your pod then this will be removed.

Comment: Thanks, but this did not help.

Answer (score 0):

GCD dispatch_group might be helpful.

a piece of code looks like this

```
dispatch_group_t myGroup = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_group_notify(myGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"all downloading requests were finished.");
});

for (int counter = 0; counter < 25; counter++) {

    dispatch_group_enter(myGroup);
    [someDownloadingRequest fireWithCompletionBlock: ^ { //fire your downloading request
        //update your downloading progress view
        dispatch_group_leave(myGroup);
    }];
}
```

Now give me my pony.